# Multiple Where Ins in search query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have three tables in an Access DB.

```
Labs (ID, TestLab)
Standards (ID, Standard, Keywords)
LabStd (ID, LabID, StdID)
```

A lab has many standards. Prior to today all I needed to do was match a search phrase to the keyword or standard columns in the `Standards` table.

```
Select Labs.ID, Labs.TestLab, Standards.standard
FROM Standards INNER JOIN (Labs INNER JOIN LabStd 
    ON Labs.ID = LabStd.LabID)
  ON Standards.ID = LabStd.StdID 
WHERE Standards.Keywords LIKE "%labstandard%"
OR Standards.standard LIKE "%labstandard%"
ORDER BY Labs.id, Standards.ID
```

Now, if a plus sign is used in the search (labstandard1+labstandard2) I need to split the string and see if a lab matches all the standards in the search. I figure I need to use a subquery for this and tried to use multiple `WHERE IN` statements but that doesn't work so I'm at a loss.

As a test I removed the `LIKE` statements and just went to equals. The following query returns no results even though there is a matching standard for each and a lab associated with both standards.

```
SELECT Labs.ID, Labs.TestLab, Standards.standard
FROM Standards INNER JOIN (Labs INNER JOIN LabStd 
    ON Labs.ID = LabStd.LabID) 
ON Standards.ID = LabStd.StdID 
WHERE LabStd.StdID IN 
    (SELECT ID AS StdID FROM Standards 
     WHERE (Standards.Keywords = 'labstandard1' 
     OR Standards.standard ='labstandard1')
    ) 
AND LabStd.StdID IN 
    (SELECT ID as StdID 
     FROM Standards
     WHERE (Standards.Keywords = 'labstandard2'
            OR Standards.standard ='labstandard2')
    ) 
ORDER BY Labs.id, Standards.ID
```

I hope I explained that clear enough, let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Comment: Access SQL uses `*` as wildcard, not `%`.

Comment: The original version of this question had asp-classic tag.  In that case, he is likely using ADO to connect to the Access db file ... therefore he **must** use ANSI wildcards (% and _ instead of \* and ?).

Comment: That is correct Hans, the single query works fine it's getting that second that is throwing me off. I'm going to give Tony's solution a try real quick and if I get no where I'll post of some data. Thanks fellas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your last query is that you're looking for a single LabStd row where StdId is in both subsets, and that isn't possible.  What you want is to find all the Labs for which both standards exist.  Someething like this:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    Labs
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT
            1
        FROM
            LabStd INNER JOIN Standards ON LabStd.StdId = Standards.Id
        WHERE
            LabStd.LabId = Labs.Id
            AND
            ( Standards.Standard = 'labstandard1' or Standards.Keywords = 'labstandard1' )
    )
    AND
    EXISTS (
        SELECT
            1
        FROM
            LabStd INNER JOIN Standards ON LabStd.StdId = Standards.Id
        WHERE
            LabStd.LabId = Labs.Id
            AND
            ( Standards.Standard = 'labstandard2' or Standards.Keywords = 'labstandard2' )
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may be, thought standard.keywords suggests that this should be a like...

```
Select ID as StdID From Standards Where 
Standards.Keywords ='labstandard1' 
OR 
Standards.standard = "labstandard1"
OR
Standards.Keywords ='labstandard2' 
OR 
Standards.standard = "labstandard2"
```

Then use All to get the labstds

```
select LabStd.LabID 
Where StdId = all (Select ID as StdID From Standards Where 
Standards.Keywords ='labstandard1' 
OR 
Standards.standard = "labstandard1"
OR
Standards.Keywords ='labstandard2' 
OR 
Standards.standard = "labstandard2")
```

Then join back to lab.

Queries like this can drive you loony. Always break them up inner to outer and confirm the parts.

Comment: I like that query because it is much cleaner than what I came up with but I still get the same results where I will get a lab that has one of the standards but not both.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution though it is mighty ugly. First here is some data.

```
**Standards**
ID      Standard        Keywords    
20      AAMA 505        Dry Shrinkage Thermal Cycling   
26      AAMA 614        High Perf. Organic Coatings on Plastic

**Labs**
ID      TestLab
10      TESTING, INC
21      LABORATORIES, INC.
3       FRESNO TESTING, INC.

**LabStd**
ID      LabID       StdID
283     3           20
284     10          20
285     21          20
291     21          26
299     10          26
```

Here is the query that works. This pulls out pulls out lab ids 10 and 21 and leaves out 3, which is correct.

```
SELECT Labs.ID, Labs.TestLab, Standards.standard
FROM Standards INNER JOIN (Labs INNER JOIN LabStd 
    ON Labs.ID = LabStd.LabID) 
ON Standards.ID = LabStd.StdID 
WHERE LabStd.StdID IN 
    (
        SELECT labs.testlab 
        FROM Standards INNER JOIN 
            (Labs INNER JOIN LabStd ON Labs.ID = LabStd.LabID) 
        ON Standards.ID = LabStd.StdID 
        WHERE standards.standard = "AAMA 505"
    ) 
AND Labs.TestLab IN 
    (
        SELECT labs.testlab 
        FROM Standards INNER JOIN 
            (Labs INNER JOIN LabStd ON Labs.ID = LabStd.LabID) 
        ON Standards.ID = LabStd.StdID 
        WHERE standards.standard = "AAMA 614"
    ) 
ORDER BY Labs.id, Standards.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use a derived table to count the number of matching standards. Then use a HAVING clause to ensure the correct number of matches.

Note: `count(*) = 2` is the number of *unique* search terms

```
SELECT  Labs.ID, Labs.TestLab, Standards.Standard
FROM  (  
          ( Labs INNER JOIN LabStd  ON Labs.ID = LabStd.LabID )
                 INNER JOIN Standards ON Standards.ID = LabStd.StdID )
                 INNER JOIN (
                        SELECT   ls.LabID, COUNT(*) AS NumMatched
                        FROM     Standards s INNER JOIN LabStd ls ON s.ID = ls.StdID
                        WHERE  ( s.standard LIKE "%AAMA 505%" OR s.Keywords LIKE "%AAMA 505%")
                        OR     ( s.standard LIKE "%AAMA 614%" OR s.Keywords LIKE "%AAMA 614%" )
                        GROUP BY ls.LabID
                        HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 
                  )  matched ON matched.LabID = Labs.ID
```